# Forçar array a ter os elementos todos em string

Tags: php, array, string

```
$values_x = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count( $series[0]['data'] ); $i++ ) {
    $values_x[] = $series[0]['data'][$i][0];
}

$values_y = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count( $series[0]['data'] ); $i++ ) {
    $values_y[] = $series[0]['data'][$i][1];
}

$categories = array(
    "label"  => $label_x,
    "values" => $values_x,
    "colors" => $eco_chart_colors,
);

$series = array("label" => null, "values" => array( array("data" => $values_y)));

} else {

    $categories = array(
        "label"  => $label_x,
        "values" => $values_x,
        "colors" => "",
    );

    $series = array("label" => $label_y, "values" => $series);

}
```

A variável `$value_x` vem como números, ex: 2010, 2011, 2012, mas preciso que sejam strings ex: '2010','2011', '2012'.
De preferência queria forçar tudo o que vem dentro do `$categories` a ser string, já tentei com `strval` mas dá-me sempre values: `null`.

Comment: Tenta fazer assim aqui: `$values_x[] = (string)$series[0]['data'][$i][0];` Leia mais sobre [typecasting aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.type-juggling.php)

Comment: @JuniorNunes: Esse teu comentário tem uma cara danada de resposta. Por que não escrever uma?

Comment: @Wtrmute por que ainda estou com dúvida se é isso mesmo que ele quer, se ele der o feedback positivo eu publico a resposta!

Comment: Não funcionou não. Se calhar é mais fácil forçar o $categories para string.  $categories = array( "label" => $label_x, "values" => $values_x, "colors" => "", ); aqui

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/50Opv.png preciso do conteudo desse "values" a aparecer como string

Comment: @user70531 é que na verdade o $values_x é o label, coloca no $values_y: `$values_y[] = (string)$series[0]['data'][$i][1];`

Comment: não, o $values_x é o que está a dar os anos ao values no json